# C++ : istringstream looping twice

Tags: c++, fileparsing, istringstream

I'm currently working on a mock process scheduler. The code reads a text file of fake processes, and I need to be able to parse through the file. Text file is formatted as shown below.

```
Pid     Bst     Arr     Pri     Dline   I/O
1       1       850     61      852     3
2       15      3980    82      3998    2
3       83      8095    51      8179    0
4       96      7262    66      7365    0
5       100     6529    1       6630    0
6       58      9068    24      9132    0
7       9       5148    35      5166    4
8       -8      5924    3       5925    0
9       100     -1      34      101     0
10      72      1918    43      -5      0
```

In order to do this, after looking for a few suggestions as to the best way to go about this, I've decided to go with an istringstream. Code as follows.

```
int parseProcessFile(String filename){
    std::ifstream infile(filename);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)){
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int pid, bst, arr, pri, dline, io;
        if (!(infile >> pid >> bst >> arr >> pri >> dline >> io) || (pid < 0 || bst < 0 || arr < 0 || pri < 0 || dline < 0 || io < 0)) { 
            //do nothing, as this line won't read in appropriately
        } // error
        printf("%d | %d | %d | %d | %d \n", pid, bst, arr, pri, dline, io);
        // save process details
    }
    return 1;
}
```

*the long if simply checks for correct inputs(no non-integers, nothing less than 0)*

For some reason, when ran, it's looped through twice completely, printing out everything that is a correct line. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: If you are using streams for everything else, why suddenly switch to `printf` for output?

Comment: Is `!(infile >>` a typo? Why aren't you reading those from the stringstream you made?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(infile >> pid >> bst >> arr >> pri >> dline >> io) ...)
```

That will read from the file (after you have already read from the file).  What you meant to do was

```
if (!(iss>> pid >> bst >> arr >> pri >> dline >> io) ...)
```

Which will parse the line you just read with `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code. Here's what I think you meant to write:

```
int parseProcessFile(string filename){
    std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)){
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int pid, bst, arr, pri, dline, io;
        if (!(iss >> pid >> bst >> arr >> pri >> dline >> io) || (pid < 0 || bst < 0 || arr < 0 || pri < 0 || dline < 0 || io < 0)) { 
            //do nothing, as this line won't read in appropriately
            continue;
        } // error
        printf("%d | %d | %d | %d | %d | %d \n", pid, bst, arr, pri, dline, io);
        // save process details
    }
    return 1;
}
```

First, unless you meant to write `String` (with a capital 'S'), you're using `std::string`, and you'll need to pass a `const char *` to ifstream's constructor.

Second, you meant to type `iss` instead of `infile`. As Zac said, you're parsing the wrong thing.

Finally, if you really don't want to do anything on an invalid line, you should put the printf in an `else`, or use `continue` to skip that loop iteration within your check for invalidity.

Hope this helps! :)